# Запрос OpenCart

Tags: sql, opencart

Есть запрос, который выводит model товара в Sal файл. Нужно в этот запрос добавить еще одну выгрузку с таблицы.

Пример:

```
$result_for_sal = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM oc_order_product WHERE order_id = (SELECT order_id FROM oc_order_product ORDER BY order_product_id DESC LIMIT 1)");
```

Нужно добавить еще таблицу oc_product_option_value, и из нее брать points. Пробую так:

```
$result_for_sal = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM oc_order_product, oc_product_option_value WHERE order_id, points = (SELECT order_id FROM oc_order_product ORDER BY order_product_id DESC LIMIT 1)");
```

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос был решен так:

Добавил:

```
$result_for_sals = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM oc_product_option_value WHERE points");

$points =  $result_for_sals->row["points"];
```